# How to fetch the output of job using Run-deck and trigger next job based on output of the previous job?

Tags: nodes, job-scheduling, rundeck

I am creating a job and triggering the output from shell script which is present in remote server. Also i could able to execute the command, but how i need to fetch that output from the executed job and based on the output i can schedule my next jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much data you need to read from the first step that runs the remote script, there are a couple of approaches:

1. Use a log filter for the first step that runs the remote script
   to parse a line of output and save it as a named key to use in the
   second step (which will perhaps be a jobref step).
2. Create a script that wraps the `[rd][1]` CLI to run the job, gets output and then make another call to `rd` to execute other jobs.